# Tomcat doesn't work when I added my dependency in pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I should develop a Spring project.

I got base source code. When I run Tomcat, it worked correctly.

But if I added a dependency which I had developed by a fat jar in pom.xml, Tomcat 
doesn't work.

I got error below:

```
18-Jan-2020 23:32:05.086 �떖媛� [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 援ъ꽦�슂�냼 [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]�쓣(瑜�) �떆�옉�븯吏� 紐삵뻽�뒿�땲�떎.
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1720)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:479)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:428)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: �씠由꾩씠 [spring_web]�씤, �몮 �씠�긽�쓽 fragment�뱾�씠 諛쒓껄�릺�뿀�뒿�땲�떎. �씠�뒗 �긽���쟻 �닚�꽌諛곗뿴�뿉�꽌 遺덊뿀�맗�땲�떎. �긽�꽭 �젙蹂대뒗 �꽌釉붾┸ �뒪�럺 8.2.2 2c �옣�쓣 李몄“�븯�떗�떆�삤. �젅���쟻 �닚�꽌諛곗뿴�쓣 �궗�슜�븯�뒗 寃껋쓣 怨좊젮�빐 蹂댁떗�떆�삤.
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.orderWebFragments(WebXml.java:2159)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1131)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:776)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5063)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 44 more
18-Jan-2020 23:32:05.106 �떖媛� [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method manageApp
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 援ъ꽦�슂�냼 [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]�쓣(瑜�) �떆�옉�븯吏� 紐삵뻽�뒿�땲�떎.
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1720)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:479)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:428)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18-Jan-2020 23:32:05.107 �떖媛� [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke Exception invoking method createStandardContext
    javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method manageApp
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:295)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:479)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:428)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
[2020-01-18 11:32:05,151] Artifact posledger-assets-dapp:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: 援ъ꽦�슂�냼 [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]�쓣(瑜�) �떆�옉�븯吏� 紐삵뻽�뒿�땲�떎.
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:747)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1720)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
        ... 35 more
18-Jan-2020 23:32:13.568 �젙蹂� [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory �쎒 �븷�뵆由ъ��씠�뀡 �뵒�젆�넗由� [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager]�쓣(瑜�) 諛곗튂�빀�땲�떎.
18-Jan-2020 23:32:13.933 �젙蹂� [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory �쎒 �븷�뵆由ъ��씠�뀡 �뵒�젆�넗由� [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager]�뿉 ���븳 諛곗튂媛� [363] 諛�由ъ큹�뿉 �셿猷뚮릺�뿀�뒿�땲�떎.
```

My fat jar works correctly when I run unit test in this project. I don't know why Tomcat doesn't work.

OS: Windows 7

JDK: 1.8.0_231

Tomcat: 8.5

IDE: Intellij Ultimate 2019.03

Comment: Which dependency you added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the scope of your added dependency as `provided`

```
<scope>provided</scope>
```

So embedded Tomcat's classes don't clash with the classes of the Tomcat to which you're deploying war file.